# How can I move one row to a specific index in the table in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

TL;DR: I gotta move a row to the first index, is there any high level function to do this?

Hey there, please be kind, I'm newish to Sequelize and have mostly been able to get across most things easily, however I need to move a row up to the first index, so it's the first row in the table. I've found on the docs something about Migrations and transactions, and it's a tad hard for me to grasp the concept of how it works properly. Is there any like high level function that just moves a row to any index given the row ID and the index?

I haven't tried anything yet, as I'm not sure what to apply exactly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.